# Stylus. Изменение названия селектора в цикле

Tags: css, препроцессор, stylus

Имеются следующие стили

```
.group-title_group-3 .group-title__wrapper
.group-title_group-4 .group-title__wrapper
.group-title_group-5 .group-title__wrapper
.group-title_group-6 .group-title__wrapper
.group-title_group-7 .group-title__wrapper
.group-title_group-8 .group-title__wrapper
.group-title_group-9 .group-title__wrapper
.group-title_group-10 .group-title__wrapper
.group-title_group-11 .group-title__wrapper
.group-title_group-12 .group-title__wrapper
   top: 129px
```

Можно задать изменение названия стиля в цикле? Для свойств stylus [поддерживает цикл for](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/iteration.html). Можно сделать аналогично для сокращения записи подобную конструкцию?

```
for i in (3..11)
    group-title_group-i .group-title__wrapper
        top: 129px
```

Или что использовать, если цикл не подходит?

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено. [Selector interpolation](http://stylus-lang.com/docs/interpolation.html#selector-interpolation)

```
for i in (3..12)
   .group-title_group-{i} .group-title__wrapper
       top: 43px
```